# Rails - yml файл для всех языков

Tags: ruby-on-rails, локализация, yml

Я переводил свое Rails-приложение и столкнулся со следуюшей проблемой. Не все элементы надо переводить. Например, в `en.yml` у меня хранятся не только фразы, но и ссылки. Переводить их не имеет смысла, но если их не включасть, например, в `ru.yml`, то будет ошибка `translation_missing`.

@MichaelRadionov посоветовал использовать наследование.

Соответственно, **вопрос**: *Как использовать наследование в YML файлах*

Comment: Может быть возможен вариант наследования перевода? Например, русский будет наследовать английский, и в файле русского перевода будут только переопределяться значения из английского. То, что не было переопределено, то останется английским.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov А как объявить наследование в YML файлах?

Comment: Вот насчет реализации я к сожалению подсказать наверное не смогу, просто подкинул возможный вариант. Может быть поможет данный хелпер - [rails-i18n-translation-inheritance-helper](https://github.com/kipcole9/rails-i18n-translation-inheritance-helper/)

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Спасибо за вариант, но всё гораздо проще :) Можете посмотреть мое решение в ответе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать наследование не нужно. Эта функция уже включена в гем `rails-i18n`. Для того что-бы все работало, нужно отредактировать файл `application.rb`:

```
# Автозагрузка всех языковых файлов
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]

# Дефолтовый язык
config.i18n.default_locale = :ru

# Возврат к английскому при ошибках
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]

# Так же можно указывать какой язык использовать при ошибках
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'ru' => 'en'}
```